# How can an autotools user specify a combination of static & dynamic linking?

Tags: autotools, static-linking, dynamic-linking, libtool

I'm building a program with autoconf, automake, and libtool.
My work requires that I statically link (most) libraries. This hasn't been
a problem in the past because I could statically link everything with
`-all-static`. Now it's a problem because I have to use a library which is
only dynamic; it was given to us by a thirdparty, and we don't have the source.

Of course, `-all-static` now causes the build to fail. Is it possible to
tell libtool to statically link everything, except for this one library?
Is it possible to have libtool do any combination of static and
dynamic linking, or is it all or nothing?

So far I've tried creating a convenience library with `LDFLAGS = -static`, which depends on the libraries I want to statically link. But libtool doesn't concatenate the static libraries, like I would have hoped. The program depending on the convenience library still dynamically links everything.

I've also tried `--disable-shared`, but that didn't affect the build.

---

These questions are similar, but don't really answer my question:

[Force linking a static library into a shared one with Libtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842949/force-linking-a-static-library-into-a-shared-one-with-libtool)

[Is it possible to link some — but not all — libraries statically with libtool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943834/is-it-possible-to-link-some-but-not-all-libraries-statically-with-libtool)

(I don't want to delete shared libraries from my system, and specifing the full path for everything is hardly better than linking by hand, but maybe it's the only way.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You did not specify the operating system, but let us assume that it is a relatively recent Unix/Linux/OSX. If it is not, then ignore the following warning.

Before I answer, you should know that mixing static and shared code on most ELF-based systems (Unix/Linux) is problematic. One reason is because it can lead to code getting out of sync if you forget to relink an updated dependency. Another is due to the nature of static code vs. [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). This is why libtool tries to discourage it.

That being said, in the Makefile.am (assuming your final program is `foo` and the shared library is):

```
    .
    .
    .
    foo_SOURCES = foo.c abc.c def.c hij.c
    foo_LDFLAGS = -all-static -Wl,-Bdynamic,-L/path/to,-lshared,-Bstatic
    foo_LDADD = -L../path/to -lbar -lbaz
```

What is important here is that libtool allows you to short-circuit the checks and GNU gcc's `-static` flag (which is used by libtool) by passing `-Wl,` arguments directly to the linker (GNU ld). To put spaces between arguments, the comma `,` delimiter is used.

Both `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic` are documented in GNU ld's [info pages](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/ld/Options.html#Options) as well as the help screen. Again, since you did not mention the os or compiler package being used, I am assuming GNU gcc and GNU ld on Linux. You may want to verify by using `ld --help` to see for yourself. If, for some reason, it is not GNU ld, then you will need to find the equivalent flags to `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic`, substituting where appropriate.

Comment: This works, but at the loss of some flexibility. I don't need a dynamic build, but if I ever did I would need to edit some `Makefile.am`s, right? This also causes problems with macros like `AC_CHECK_LIB` (which just adds a `-l` to `LIBS`), but I guess that's to be expected.

Comment: I gave the simplest approach possible. However, for something fancy, you could pull the flags into your `configure.ac`. Once there, you could add `DYNLIBS="-Wl,-Bdynamic,-L/path/to,-lshared,-Bstatic"` with a call to `AC_SUBST([DYNLIBS])`. Then all you'd need to do is call `$(DYNLIBS)` in your `Makefile.am`. This would give you a more control, but remember that `AC_CHECK_LIBS` doesn't check for static vs. dynamic libs. Is that what you want or is there something else that would make it more flexible?

Comment: I am trying to do the opposite: link all libraries dynamically except given one (on the example of `cjpeg` target in [`Makefile.am`](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/blob/master/Makefile.am#L119)). I have changed `cjpeg_LDADD = -ljpeg` and added `cjpeg_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Bstatic,-ljpeg,-Bdynamic` but still `libjpeg.so` is added to parameters and linked dynamically. If I say `cjpeg_LDADD = ` it complains about missing symbols. If I say `cjpeg_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-static` it fails with "attempted static link of dynamic object". The library itself is part of build process – maybe that causes the problem?

Comment: Just discovered from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10852489/267197) that one can achieve this via `./configure --disable-shared` (no further tricks with `Makefile.am` are necessary). Looks like this is the only workaround at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to link `labA` statically, but `pthread` dynamically. If I add `libA` to the `Makefile.am` as

```
my_proc_LDADD = -Wl,-Bstatic -lA -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

then `ldd` cannot link `libA`.
`libA` should to specify in `LDADD`, but autotools does not allow it.

If I add to the `Makefile.am` `LDADD` as a comment

```
#my_proc_LDADD = -Wl,-Bstatic -lA -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

then it will also get added into the resulting `Makefile` as a comment
So I simply uncomment this string after `configure` script:

```
./configure
sed -i -e 's/#my_proc_LDADD/my_proc_LDADD/g' ./src/Makefile
make
```

and as a result, statically linked `libA` is appended to `LDADD`